# Broadcasting object to multiple clients through socket java

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I need to create an application where a client can send a message (in form of a an object) to the server, who then will broadcast the message to the other clients.

I'm having some trouble with the `ObjectInputStream.readobject()` for the clients receiving messages from the server. In the thread listening to the server on the client side the print "waiting to read object" gets printed out in an infinite loop, but "read object" and "printed" is never shown. Why is that?

**Thread on client side listening to server**

```
while (!terminate){

        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting to read object");
            ChatMessage msg = (ChatMessage) is.readObject();

            System.out.println("Read object");
            System.out.println(msg.toString());
            System.out.println("Printed");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Writing to server client side**

```
while(!terminate){

        String message = scanner.nextLine();

        if(message.equals("logout")){
            terminateProgram();
            return;
        }

        ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage(name,message);

        try {
            os.writeObject(msg);
            os.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Sending message to server failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Reading messages from client and broadcasting them (server side)**

```
while (!terminate) {

        try {
            Object obj = is.readObject();

            if (obj instanceof ChatMessage) {

                ArrayList<Socket> sockets = SingletonModel.getInstance().getSockets();

                for (Socket socketOne : sockets) {
                    if (socket != socketOne) {
                        System.out.println("We here");
                        os = new ObjectOutputStream(socketOne.getOutputStream());
                        os.writeObject(obj);
                        os.flush();
                        System.out.println("We done");
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Properly handling the `IOException` in client might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find this *ObjectInputStream.readobject()* in your codes, you mentioned it but didn't show it.

In the server side you send the object in this way (note that don't forget to *serialize* the object):

```
class Message implements Serializable{
  public String getMessage(){
   return "message";
}
}
```

---

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3451);
  Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
  ObjectOutputStream outs = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            outs.writeObject(new Message());
```

In the client side you should retrieve the object in this way

```
  // or, Socket client = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 3451);
 Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 3451);
 InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
   ObjectInputStream ins = new ObjectInputStream(inFromServer);
          try {
              Message message= (Message ) ins.readObject();
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) { }
```

Comment: The ObjectInputStream is the "is" variable in the first code example. I changed my code to your implementation, but it still prints out "waiting to read object" in an infinite loop (too much output too process).

Comment: It's hard to think by just looking at your very *short* codes, there isn't enough information.